# renaming multiple files in a folder counting up from 001 to xxx in R

Tags: r, web-scraping, rename, file-rename

I would like to rename a list of files that I have saved in a folder. The names of the files currently look like this:

```
000_html-code.html
...
217_html-code.html
```

for working with the files, I would like to start at 001, also there are some file numbers missing, i.e. 163, which causes problems for R. Thus, I would like to name them:

```
001_html-code.html
...
216_html-code.html
```

I have tried the following code, but apart from not doing the magic on xxx-xxx (rather using 1:216), it also throws an error message ('from' and 'to' argument not of same length):

```
d <- list.files("C:/Users/[NAME]/Desktop/[FOLDER NAME]")
lapply(d, function (name) {
  file.rename("*_html-code.html", paste0(1:216,"_html-code"))
})
```

What am I doing wrong?

Many thanks!

Comment: from is `"*_html-code.html"`, to is `paste0(1:216,"_html-code"))` (a 216-element vector). So the lengths are not the same. Also, you never use the `name` param in your function

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for a `lapply` loop, `file.rename` is vectorized.
Try this:

```
d <- list.files("C:/Users/[NAME]/Desktop/[FOLDER NAME]")
file.rename(d, sprintf("%03d_html-code", seq_along(d)))
```

Note the use of `sprintf` in order to have 3 digits numbers.

Comment: thanks! It does not give me an error message, but somehow returns FALSE for all files and does not rename them :-/

Comment: @Carolin Try to see if you are reading the directory correctly. What are the contents of `d`? I would use the function `list.files` argument `pattern` to get predictable results. (I have tried it with a small set of files and it worked.)

Comment: :@Rui Barradas: so sorry for coming back with more questions. Setting the pattern worked to identify the folder, however, now all files are deleted from the folder. Are they saved somewhere else?

Comment: I had also set the full.names = T this time, as it worked in some previous piece of code

Comment: It actually works now. I think there was a problem with the naming of 1 file, so I had used a version of the raw data without corrected names. I extended the sprintf with .html to get html files as the output. Thanks again!

Comment: @Carolin Glad that it worked. As for the files being deleted, this is because it is a file rename function. If you want to keep the original files maybe `file.copy` is better.